# Weird syntax error 'error: expected one of `,` or `:`, found `else`'

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, rust, rust-cargo

Currently I'm working on a VM written in Rust. There are two syntax errors I'm running into both of which I'm struggling to solve as they don't seem to quite make sense to me.

Here is the code:

```
pub fn aaa(vm: &mut VM, pipeline: &Pipeline, _hv: &mut dyn Hypervisor) -> Result<(), VMError>{
    let mut al = vm.get_reg(Reg8::AL as u8, ValueSize::Byte)?.u8_exact()?;
    let ah = vm.get_reg(Reg8::AH as u8, ValueSize::Byte)?.u8_exact()?;
    let adjust = vm.flags.adjust;
    if (al & 0x0F) > 9 | | adjust {
        vm.set_reg(Reg8::AL as u8, SizedValue::Byte(al1.overflowing_add(6)));
        vm.set_reg(Reg8::AH as u8, SizedValue::Byte(ah.overflowing_add(1)));
        vm.flags.adjust = true;
        vm.flags.carry = true;
    } else {
        vm.flags.adjust = false;
        vm.flags.carry = false;
    }
    al = vm.get_reg(Reg8::AL as u8, ValueSize::Byte)?.u8_exact()?;
    vm.set_reg(Reg8::AL as u8, SizedValue::Byte(al2 & 0x0F));
    Ok(())
}
```

The errors I'm getting are here:

```
error: expected `,`
   --> src/ops.rs:738:9
    |
738 |         vm.set_reg(Reg8::AL as u8, SizedValue::Byte(al1.overflowing_add(6)));
    |         ^^

   --> src/ops.rs:738:9
    |
738 |         vm.set_reg(Reg8::AL as u8, SizedValue::Byte(al1.overflowing_add(6)));
    |         ^^

error: expected one of `,` or `:`, found `else`
   --> src/ops.rs:742:7
    |
742 |     } else {
    |       ^^^^ expected one of `,` or `:` here
```

I'm merely trying to access the struct field implemented functions, I'm not sure why the compiler would tell me to use a comma instead of the period. Furthermore I have no idea why it's expecting a comma or a colon instead of my else statement. The if else appears to be perfectly aligned. Anyone else running into this? Is this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `| |` in the if condition. That parses not as a logical OR (`||`) but as two separate bitwise OR operators (`|`). Just change it to `||` without space inbetween.

A minimal example:

```
fn main() {
    let adjust = true;
    let al = 0xFF;

    /* does not parse:
    if (al & 0x0F) > 9 | | adjust {
    }
    */

    if (al & 0x0F) > 9 || adjust {
    }
}
```